# Python pyopencl Import Error

Tags: python-2.7, pyopencl

I am using Windows 10 and getting the same error. 
I have **AMD Radeon HD 5000** series GPU.
I installed **OpenCL 2.0.4.0** 
When I run:

```
import pyopencl
```

I am getting this error:

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-63105a952239> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyopencl

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py in <module>()
     32 
     33 try:
---> 34     import pyopencl.cffi_cl as _cl
     35 except ImportError:
     36     import os

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\cffi_cl.py in <module>()
     37 from pytools import memoize_method
     38 
---> 39 from pyopencl._cffi import ffi as _ffi
     40 from .compyte.array import f_contiguous_strides, c_contiguous_strides
     41 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found answer to my question. 
After I install Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications 2016, errors are disappeared. I think now when I run my code it is using intel video cord not my dedicated ATI card. I dont know how to check which one is running.

Comment: you select the device (gpu or cpu) in which you run your kernel once you create a new context.